# Haskell parameters - comparison operators

Tags: haskell

I'd like to define a function whose parameter takes in a list and an operator. This is what I currently have. I'm trying to define a higher order function that can find the minimum or the maximum.

```
largest :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a
largest = findType (>)

findType :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> a
findType op [] = error "empty list"
findType op [x] = x
findType op (x:xs) 
    | x op maxTail = x
    | otherwise = maxTail
    where maxTail = findType op xs
```

However, it's not currently working.

Comment: Operator type? Operators are just functions.

Comment: So how would I define a function that takes in an operator as a parameter then?

Comment: Surround them in parenthesis. ie `(+)`

Comment: Oops, I messed up the phrasing of my question. Please see my edited question, which asks how to define a function that takes in an operator as a parameter rather than how to pass in an operator as an argument.

Comment: Maybe try taking a look at the standard `map` function? http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Base.html#map

Answer (score 3):

You can either write a function that accepts any `a -> a -> Bool` function parameter, or use the fact that comparable data types implement [Ord](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aOrd) class.

Here is a piece of code showing both methods to check if a list is sorted

```
option1 :: (a->a->Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
option1 op (a:b:ls) = op a b && option1 op (b:ls)
option1 op _ = True

option2 :: (Ord a) => Ordering -> [a] -> Bool
option2 op (a:b:ls) = compare a b == op && option2 op (b:ls)
option2 op _ = True

main = do
   let ls = [1, 2, 3]
   print $ option1 (<) ls
   print $ option2 LT ls
```

Note that the 2nd method requires the use of `Ordering` data type which only has values `LT`, `EQ` and `GT` (meaning <, = and > respectively). You could make it more flexible by passing, say, a list of acceptable `Ordering` values or some other data structure, however, in most cases 1st option is more appropriate.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but I've run into some trouble. Can you please see my edited post?

Comment: `findType` expected a function for it's first argument, but you gave it a list, hence the error. Similarly, you've defined `largest` to take a function argument, but wrote in such way that it would actually  need a list.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as two different problems. Let's address the one generating the compiler error first.

You gave to `findType` the following signature:

```
findType :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> a
```

the intent being to extract from the list given as the second parameter the bound as dictated by the ordering predicate provided as the first parameter.

However, in the last line of the very  `findType` function definition, you bind `maxTail` to the expression `findType xs`, which omits the predicate.

The correct line is of course:

```
where maxTail = findType op xs
```

Your second error is related to the signature of the `largest` function, but I will let you find out exactly what it is.

Comment: Hmm.. well from what I can see, `largest` doesn't really have any parameters, but it does return something. I'm not sure, am I having going in the right direction?

Comment: what ddo you want it to do,?

Comment: I want to use largest as a higher order function, so I was just following the example here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Higher_order_function which does this: 
`multList n [] = []`
`multList n (x:xs) = n*x : multList n xs`
`tripleList = multList 3`

Comment: yes, that's the implementation part, but wrt the surrounding programme, what behaviour this function should have? what does it work on? what is its result? answer these two last questions and you will know the correct sig. for your function.

Comment: alrighty then, glad to be of help. If you have other questions, don't hesitate to use this website.

Answer (score 1):

GHC doesn't know that you want to use the function **op** as an operator into your code, you must tell him, but how can you do that ?

Let's consider the **elem** function, this function take a value and a list and return True or False depending if the value is present into the list or not.

```
elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem 2 [1,2,3] => True
```

Basically it's see as a function, and if you want to use them as an operator which can be really useful, you must enclose it with **`**.

```
2 `elem` [1,2,3] => True
```

If you add the remarks of didierc on the call of findType into the where clause, you'll have a working code.

Anyway, It's a very bad idea to put a recursive call into a guard, the code is hardest to read, and I'm not sure be it could lead to performance issue. You need to learn how to use an accumulator, take a look on [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions)

---

**Note**
Conversely when a function is considered by default as an operator, to use it as a function just enclose it with **()**.

```
2 : [] => [2]

(:) 2 [] => [2]
```

Comment: Hmm, if it's bad to put a recursive call into a guard, how else can I write my code?

Comment: This is not the good question, the good one is what's wrong with my code ? ... It lead us to, findType (==) [1,2,3] => 3 ... you've surely go on the wrong way, findType (>) should works as maximum and findType (<) should work as minimum then why do you use (>) or (<) function and not max and min ???? Try to rewrite it using max and not (>) and, magically, no more recursive call into a guard, no more error case to manage, no more strange where clause, just a pure straightforward function. maximun of [1,2,3] == max 1 (max 2 3)  ;)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to say, but you're right, a better question I should have asked was "What is wrong with my code?" But anyways, if I use max, then I can't use (<) for my find type function because it'll always find the max, right? Unless I have a `case of`. Also, I don't think my code should work for the == operator, because it has nothing to compare to except each element in the list with themselves.

Comment: What's your goal ? Put (>) into your code ? or rewrite maximum (or) minimum function using high order function ? I'd like to say that an operator which retrieve a bool should be use as a predicate then it should be use to skill value not to accumulate one. (>) to filter a list ok, but not to compare one by one all the item of a list.

Comment: The only way to accumulate a result as you want using a Boolean operator is to have a function which retrieve a Boolean as Karolis Juodelė have show you, then you can chain each recursive call without loosing the Boolean context using && or ||

Comment: but as you want to retrieve something which are not a Boolean the use of a Boolean operator (>) is not well fit. I can't say more without giving you the solution, I don't have any more argument.